# What are the various function to free memory in Android?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

Could you please tell me what are the various functions which we could use to free memory on android device. One i have figured out is `KillBackgroundProcess()`.

Are there more functions like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [MediaPlayer#release](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release%28%29)
- [AudioTrack#release](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#release%28%29)
- [Bitmap#recycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29)
- [TypedArray#recycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#recycle%28%29)

Many of the heavier objects or objects expected to be used and reused frequently have `release` or `recycle` methods. The above are the main ones I've used.

For further examples see the API search results for:

- [recycle](http://developer.android.com/search.html#q=recycle&t=0)
- [release](http://developer.android.com/search.html#q=release&t=2)